# How to use my reputation and badges blog in my site as Image

Tags: support, flair

I can see there are users using their name, reputation and badges as a image block on their sites. I hope stackoverflow provides an option like RSS.

Please suggest how to use this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You're looking for Flair.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4345707/imaphpdeveloper/flair)  That page has all of the information you need otherwise.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the one I am looking for, is there any way to customize the image? I would like to show the age on this community? Means member from since?